# Weak Law of Large Numbers Question

Tags: probability

> So the WLLN states that
>   $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ : \ \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon) = 0.$$
>   But
>   $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ : \ |\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x,$$ right? So why is the WLLN not states as $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x) = 0$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} \bar{X}_n = \mu_x$?

This makes the intuition of it much clearer, so why is it not stated like this?

Comment: That is because $P(|\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon) \to 0$ tells not much about the point-wise statement $|\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon$. This need not hold even for all sufficiently large $n$, let alone the fact that for different $\epsilon$ you may need different $n$'s for which this is true. And most of all, there are counter-examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your last notion is wrong, since the theorem states that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n \stackrel{p}{=}\mu_x$ and not that they are truly equal.

One reason why it is not stated the way you describe is that it wouldn't be as clear that it implies convergence in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Your first notion is not correct because $P[\bar X_n\neq \mu_x]=1$ for all distributions on $\bar X_n$ that has a continuous density. Hence, no such $\bar X_n$ would satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr[\bar X_n\neq\mu_x]=0$.

For the second notion, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n=\mu_x$ is too strong for $\bar X_n$ to converge in probability to $\mu_n$. This is actually closer to *convergence almost surely*, which states that $\Pr[\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n=\mu_x]=1$ and is known to be strictly stronger than convergence in probability. Note that this notion is still weaker that what you have written down, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar X_n$ is allowed to differ from $\mu_x$ on a set of $\bar X_n$ with measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x) = 0$$

is false, it doesn't follow. Consider for example that $X_i$  is iid fair Bernoulli (takes values $0,1$ with same probability). Then the probability of the event $\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x$ is $1$ for $n$ odd, and for $n$ even it tends 
to $1$.

Regarding

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bar{X}_n = \mu_x$$

notice that $ \bar{X}_n$ is a random value. So you need to be careful. What do you mean by that limit? Do you mean that "always" (for all realizations) the limit holds? Then you are speaking of "[sure convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Sure_convergence)" - which is a well defined concept, but also a too strong and rarely useful one - and it doesn't hold here (there are possible sequences where the limit does not hold, eg all zeroes).

Do you mean that that limit holds "with probability one"? Then you are speaking of ["almost sure" convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence). But the weak law does not guarantee you that. You need the [strong law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law).

> But $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ : \ |\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon \qquad
>  \iff \qquad \bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x,$$ right?

That would be right if $\bar{X}_n $ were a fixed number. Here, it's a random variable. And we are not claiming that $\ |\bar{X}_n - \mu_x| \geq \epsilon$ , only that the probability of that event tends to zero.

Comment: "Then the probability of the event $\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x$ is strictly zero for $n$ odd"
I really don't follow this. So $X_i$ is Bernoulli with probability $\theta$ of taking the value $1$, right? So if we had odd $n$, such as $n=3$ then you're saying the probability that $\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_X$ is 0, which means the sample mean must equal $\mu_X=\theta$. But as long as $\theta>0$ then it's perfectly possible to get $0$ for all 3 trials, in which case $\bar{X}_n= \frac{0}{3}\neq\theta$... What am I missing?

Comment: @Refnom95 Sorry, I meant "strictly one". Fixed.

Comment: Well equally, if $\theta=\frac{1}{3}$ then it's perfectly possible to get $X_1=0$, $X_2=0$, $X_3=1$ for example in which case $\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{3}=\theta$?

Comment: My example dealt with $\theta=1/2$ (fair coin). If you want another example, take $\theta = \sqrt{2}/2$, then $\bar{X}_n \neq \mu_x$ always.